# How to sum the numbers and multiply it by the count of their sequence(Java)?

Tags: java

The input comes from the console as a single line, holding the numbers. After each number i have a character(S, H, D or C). Need to sum the numbers and only when two or more characters come sequentially, to multiply the sum by the count of the character’s sequence.

> For example, **2C 3C 5C 15S 10H 12H 2S 14D** has value **(2 + 3 + 5)
>   * 3 + 15 + (10 + 12) * 2 + 2 + 14 = 105.**

I can only extract and sum the numbers, but nothing more.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String[] input = br.readLine().split(" ");
        int sum = 0;

        for (String s : input) {
            String number = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
            sum += Integer.parseInt(number);
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to use Java?
Is that project requirement or just best-known language?

Comment: How? By writing some code. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Show us, and describe your *specific* problem better.

Comment: as you have extracted the sum, then problem are you facing in getting the count?

Comment: Need to take and sum  each number. After that to see if there is a sequence of same characters and to multiply it with the sum. For instance i have input 2C 3C 5C 10S 10H and sequence of character (C). I have to sum the numbers and multiply it by the by the count of C (2+3+5)* 3 . After that came 10S and 10H. Here we can't find a sequnce(S and H are not the same),  so just add the numbers (2+3+5)* 3 + 10 + 10.  Finaly i have to print the result . So far i can sum the numbers and nothing more !

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String[] input = br.readLine().split(" "); 
    int sum = 0;
    String tmpLetter = null;
    int tmpSum = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for (String s : input) { 
        int number = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, s.length() - 1));
        String letter = s.substring(s.length() - 1);

        if(tmpLetter == null || tmpLetter.equals(letter)){
            count++;
            tmpSum += number;
        } else {
            sum += tmpSum * count;
            count = 1;
            tmpSum = number;
        }
        tmpLetter = letter;
    }
    sum += tmpSum * count;
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `String letter = s.substring(s.length() - 1)`